# irreducibility of $m$th cyclotomic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ implies irreducibility in $\mathbb Q[x]$? (Ireland and Rosen)

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

In Chapter 13 of Ireland and Rosen's *An Introduction to Classical Modern Algebra*, they prove that the $m$th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Immediately afterwards they state a corollary which is dependent upon the same polynomial being irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$. I know that the cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ but the fact that Ireland and Rosen's book didn't explicitly use that fact grabs my attention.

Does irredubility in $\mathbb Z[x]$ of the cyclotomic polynomial imply the same for $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Comment: Gauss' Lemma: a primitive polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is irreducible if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic words are: [Gauss Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29)